# C++ Kill thread

Tags: c++, многопоточность

В 11 стандарте C++ есть какие нибудь возможности убить/завершить поток?
Подобие такого:

```
ACE_OS::thr_exit();
```

или

```
boost thread interrupt.
```

Comment: К изложенным ниже ответам, я бы еще добавил, что `std::thread` перекочевал в C++11 именно из boost и по инициативе и под чутким руководством разработчика этого класса. И если он не перенес в стандарт из своего детища возможность завершения потока кривым способом, то, вероятно, на то были веские причины.

Answer (score 3):

Явной возможности убить поток (как я понимаю речь идет о `std::thread`) нет. В этом нет необходимости. Завершайте поток корректно посредством окончания работы его функции. Если у Вас так не получается, то, скорее всего, имеете не правильную архитектуру программы.

Answer (score 2):

Убийство потока приводит к неопределенному поведению, по этому в стандартной библиотеке такого нет.

Interrupt из boost не убивает поток, а бросает исключение из wait-функций (мест где возможно прерывание). Впрочем в стандартной библиотеке такого нет.

Используйте потоки из Boost, или пишите свой механизм `interrupt`.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не можете правильно убить поток так, чтобы при этом не пострадала программа. Например, поток может находится в середине какой-нибудь критической операции (сбрасывать данные на диск, или просто держать mutex, или находится в середине выделения памяти и модификации списка свободных блоков). Нет никакой возможности гарантировать, что программа после убийства потока будет в правильном состоянии.

По этой причине стандарт и не разрешает вам убивать потоки.

Ваши потоки должны сотрудничать. Например, они могут время от времени опрашивать флаг, который просит их корректно завершить работу. (Только не забудьте синхронизацию при доступе к разделяемой переменной!)

Answer (score 1):

Как уже сказали, в самом стандарте такого решения нет, но в стандарте есть решение, которое может помочь: [std::thread::native_handle](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle). Вот как можно убить поток в Windows:

```
#include <thread>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    std::thread thr([] {while(true);});
    TerminateThread(thr.native_handle(), 0);
    thr.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Но это всё интересно лишь в академическом плане — потоки убивать нельзя(по крайней мере пока у Вас нет действительно серьёзного обоснования)

Comment: @orion_gm, соответственно, для Linux  (\*nix) можете почитать про [pthread_cancel](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html) и [pthread_kill](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html)